# undocumented jQuery .ready function signature

Tags: jquery

I found that I can pass an array of callbacks to jQuery(document).ready():

```
var test1 = function(){alert('test1')}, test2 = function(){alert('test2')};
$(document).ready([test1,test2])​
```

It doesn't work with .bind() or its aliases such as .click().  A quick test in jsfiddle shows that this functionality has been around since at least jQuery 1.5.2, but I don't see it documented anywhere.  Am I just missing it in the docs?  Is there a downside to using an undocumented function signature?  And as a side question, are there other useful undocumented jQuery features which you have found useful?

Comment: That's because jQuery uses [`Callbacks.add`](http://api.jquery.com/callbacks.add/) [internally](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/src/core.js#L258). Interestingly, the implementation is different in the development version of the code (passing the argument to `.done()` of a promise object). It should not make a difference but just shows that this behaviour could change easily.

Comment: development team could tell you about numerous undocumented things you could do... but highly doubt they'll ring you up to let you know when they break them

Comment: @FelixKling. If it does work, it's weird, as jQuery calls `ready` only if it gets a function. [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/src/core.js#L176) there is no array overload in the source code.

Comment: @gdoron: You are talking about `$([...])` which would not work, you are right. But calling `.ready` directly (`$(document).ready([...])`) does, and that's what Brian is doing.

Comment: @FelixKling. ummmm. Another reason why not using this thing. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a downside to using an undocumented function signature?

**Yes.**

O.k. I'll add one more sentence: If it's not document, it's not support => not reliable.